# Search exact word in NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsrange

I need to find a word or several words. With this method, however, I find also piece of word.

```
NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchField.text];
NSRange range = [textString rangeOfString : searchString];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {


        NSLog(@"textString = %@", textString);

    }
```

I need the word / words exact

How can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways of parsing/finding sub-strings in NSString:

- NSString itself
- NSRegularExpression.   This would probably better suit your needs since you can tackle the scenario of surrounding white-spaces around words. Thus is won't return the `cat` from `catapult` when searching for `cat`.
- NSScanner *(most likely overkill for you needs)*

... and they, of course, each have their PROs and CONs.

[NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003744) has 9 methods grouped under "Finding Characters and Substrings".  Methods such as:

> **-rangeOfString:**
>   Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the receiver.

[NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708) has 5 methods grouped under "Searching Strings Using Regular Expressions".  Methods such as:

> **-numberOfMatchesInString: options: range:**
>   Returns the number of matches of the regular expression within the specified range of the string.

It might also be useful to know about [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003726), but this class would be more useful if you're parsing the string than simply looking for sub-parts.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you add a space at the end of the search string, like so:

```
NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",searchField.text];
```

If the string from `searchField.text` already ends with a space, you would have to remove it.

This is not a perfect solution yet, for example you would not find the search string if it is at the end of a sentence. Instead what you could do is not adding the whitespace character, but instead look at the character after the hit and make sure that it is not a letter. For this, take a look at the class `NSCharacterSet`:

```
NSCharacterSet * letters = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
if (![letters characterIsMember:[textString characterAtIndex:(range.location+searchString.length)]]) {
... 
}
```